# Bash: How to replace a prefix of folders

Tags: bash, replace

I have a bunch of folders:

```
test_001
test_002
```

and I would like to replace the prefix *test* with *ftp* to get:

```
ftp_001
ftp_002
```

One problem: I have access on a Linux-Server with minimal installation. For example, rename is not installed and probably even sed is not installed. so, how can I replace the prefix using pure bash?

Comment: What did you try for yourself? We need to see a minimal amount of code to know for sure that you've made a try atleast

Comment: @Inian I'm new with bash and usually I use Perl on Windows for this kind of things. From web I found this: `for i in $test*; do mv "$i" "${i/'test'/}";done`. This code removes the prefix. Then  I could add the new prefix: `for i in $test*; do mv "$i" "test$i";done`. This works but I wanted to have solution which I better understand since the first part of this code is cryptic for me (what means i/). Usually I can catch the meaning but not in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This little script may help:

```
for dir in */
do
    mv "$dir" "${dir/test/ftp}"
done
```

execute it under the parent of your `test_00x` directory.

It could be written in a compact one-liner:

```
for dir in */; do mv "$dir" "${dir/test/ftp}"; done
```

Comment: The advantage of this solution is that it consider only files with *test*.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a minimal installation I have tried to make a command that does not require `tr`, `sed` or `find`.

**INPUT:**

```
$ tree .
.
├── a
├── b
├── c
├── test_001
└── test_002

2 directories, 3 files
```

**CMD:**

```
for d in */; do mv "${d:0:-1}" "ftp"${d:4:-1}; done
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
tree .
.
├── a
├── b
├── c
├── ftp_001
└── ftp_002

2 directories, 3 files
```

Explanations about `substrings` in bash : https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Comment: Thanks. Very useful. I accepted Kents solution since it consider only files with the prefix. If should have asked the question considering also directories which I do not want to change (not only a,b,c but also tttt_xxx).